# What's the fastest way to find the nearest Positive Definite Matrix?

Tags: functions, numerics, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

Let's assume that I have a symmetric matrix $A$. What's the fastest way to find its nearest positive definite matrix in Mathematica?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Diagonalize, zero out negative values on the diagonal, reverse, and you have the closest positive semidefinite matrix.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for the comment. However I need positive definite. Is there a way from a semidefinite, to obtain a positive definite?

Comment: Positive semi-definite is the best you can do.  What's the smallest positive number?

Comment: @mikado before, or after the transformation suggested by Daniel?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Asking for a a positive definite matrix is like asking which number in the open interval (0, 1) is nearest to 2

Comment: What people are trying to say is that there is no "nearest" PD matrix, only PSD.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, what's the fastest way to diagonalize in mathematica?

Comment: My guess would be using Eigenvalues. This might be numerically fraught if there are multiple eigenvalues though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau for 4 by 4 it's probably ok.  Thanks ;)

Comment: Positively definitely...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I just found this in R. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/nearPD.html

I wish Mathematica had one... =D

Comment: By the way, it is `Eigensystem` that I had in mind, not `Eigenvalues` alone.

Comment: As for that R routine, my guess is it amounts to modifying zero eigenvalues by the given tolerance.